# Case-insensitive storage and unicode compatibility

Tags: unicode, compatibility

After I heard of someone at my work using `String.toLowerCase()` to store case-insensitive codes in a database for searchability, I had an [epic fail](http://msmvps.com/blogs/jon_skeet/archive/2009/11/02/omg-ponies-aka-humanity-epic-fail.aspx) moment thinking about the number of ways that it can go wrong:

- Turkey test (in particular changing locales on the running computer)
- [Unicode version upgrades](https://github.com/apache/lucene-solr/blob/trunk/lucene/JRE_VERSION_MIGRATION.txt) - I mean, who knows about this stuff? If I upgrade to Java 7, I have to reindex my data if I'm being case-insensitive?

What technologies are affected by Unicode versions?

Do I need to worry about Oracle or SQL Server (or other vendors) changing their unicode versions and resulting in one of my locales not resulting in the same lower or upper character conversion?

How do I manage this? I'm tempted by the "simplicity" of ensuring I use the database conversion, but when there's an upgrade it'll be the same sort of issue.

Answer (score 41):

You do not want to store the lowercase version of a string "for searchability"!!

That is the wrong approach altogether.  You are making unjust and incorrect assumptions about how Unicode casing works.

This is why Unicode defines a separate thing called a casefold for a string, distinct from the three different cases (lowercase, titlecase, and uppercase).

Here are ten different examples **where you will do the wrong thing** if you use the lowercase instead of the casefold:

```
ORIGINAL        CASEFOLD        LOWERCASE   TITLECASE  UPPERCASE
========================================================================
eﬃcient         efficient       eﬃcient       Eﬃcient         EFFICIENT       
ﬂour            flour           ﬂour           Flour           FLOUR           
poſt            post            poſt           Poſt            POST            
poﬅ             post            poﬅ             Poﬅ            POST            
ﬅop             stop            ﬅop            Stop            STOP            
tschüß          tschüss         tschüß         Tschüß         TSCHÜSS         
weiß            weiss           weiß           Weiß            WEISS           
WEIẞ            weiss           weiß            Weiß           WEIẞ            
στιγμας         στιγμασ         στιγμας         Στιγμας         ΣΤΙΓΜΑΣ 
ᾲ στο διάολο    ὰι στο διάολο   ᾲ στο διάολο    Ὰͅ Στο Διάολο   ᾺΙ ΣΤΟ ΔΙΆΟΛΟ
```

And yes, I know the plural of stigma is stigmata not stigmas; I am trying to show the final sigma issue. Both ς and σ are valid lowercase versions of the uppercase sigma, Σ.  If you store “just the lowercase”, then you will get the wrong thing.

If you are using Java’s `Pattern` class, you must specify both `CASE_INSENSITIVE` and `UNICODE_CASE`, and you still will not get these right, because while Java uses full casemapping, it uses only simple casefolding. **This is a problem.**

As for the Turkic languages, yes, it is true that there is a special casefold for Turkic.  For example, *İstanbul* has a Turkic casefold of just *ı̇stanbul* instead of the *i̇stanbul* that you are supposed to get.  Since I am sure those will not look right to you, I’ll spell it out with named characters for the non-ASCII;  in plainer terms, `"\N{LATIN CAPITAL LETTER I WITH DOT ABOVE}stanbul"` has a Turkic casefold of `"\N{LATIN SMALL LETTER DOTLESS I}\N{COMBINING DOT ABOVE}stanbul"` rather than `"i\N{COMBINING DOT ABOVE}stanbul"` that you normally get.

Here are a couple more table rows if you’re writing a regression testing suite:

```
[ "Henry Ⅷ", "henry ⅷ", "henry ⅷ", "Henry Ⅷ", "HENRY Ⅷ",  ],
[ "I Work At Ⓚ",  "i work at ⓚ",  "i work at ⓚ", "I Work At Ⓚ", "I WORK AT Ⓚ", ],
[ "ʀᴀʀᴇ", "ʀᴀʀᴇ", "ʀᴀʀᴇ", "Ʀᴀʀᴇ", "ƦᴀƦᴇ",  ],
[ "Ԧԧ", "ԧԧ", "ԧԧ", "Ԧԧ", "ԦԦ",   ],
[ "", "", "", "", "",   ],
[ "Ὰͅ", "ὰι", "ᾲ", "Ὰͅ", "ᾺΙ",  ],
```

Where each column is orig, fold, lc, tc, and uc, just as I had in the earlier table above. Notice again how the last row has a casefold that is different from its lowercase.

Comment: So you're saying I should use casefolding? Is http://www.w3.org/International/wiki/Case_folding#Recommendations_for_Case_Folding the correct recommendation?

Comment: @Stephen: Yes, use casefolds. The w3.org recommendation is generally right but Java’s `equalsIgnoreCase` is broken. It doesn’t use Unicode casefolding tables, so misreports `"weiß"` and `"WEIẞ"` as not being equal except for case, and they certainly are. It also has a silly idea about lengths not changing, because it uses the char upper/lower instead of the string upper/lower.  For example, the uppercase string for `"weiß"` is `"WEISS"`. In Unicode, two strings are case-insensitively the same **if they have the same casefolds.** So I’d store the casefolds only, then fold my search terms, too.

Comment: @Stephen [Ucharacter.foldCase（String str, int options）](http://icu-project.org/apiref/icu4j/com/ibm/icu/lang/UCharacter.html) is what you want, making sure to use the String version. There’s also a `CaseInsensitiveString` class in ICU that you might look into.

Comment: @Stephen: Win win! I just verified that ICU4J’s `CaseInsensitiveString.equals` gets the right answers where regular Java fails; for example: `"ﬂour and water"` & `"FLOUR AND WATER"`,
`"eﬃcient"` & `"EFFICIENT"`,
`"poﬅ"` & `"post"`,
`"weiß"` & `"WEIẞ"`,
`"tschüß"` & `"TSCHÜSS"`,
`"ᾲ στο διάολο"` & `"Ὰͅ Στο Διάολο"`,
and `"ᾲ στο διάολο"` & `"ᾺΙ ΣΤΟ ΔΙΆΟΛΟ"`. That’s cause it actually uses the casefold.

Comment: On another answer, you say that "Java6's `toLowerCase()` is buggy. You really need Java7". In Java 7, does `toLowerCase()` and `toUpperCase()` do casefolding correctly?

Comment: @Stephen: Yes, Java7 does full casemapping on any code point using `toLowerCase()` and `toUpperCase()`. In Java6, it only did so on code points that were cased Letters already, so missed the case-changing numbers, symbols, and the (one) mark. However, those are casemaps only, not casefolds. Java should do simple (not full) casefolds iff you use its `UNICODE_CASE` flag w/`CASE_INSENSITIVE`. I can’t check right now because I would have to install Java7 on a machine that isn’t mine to check (JDK releases trail behind for Macs, which are my main machines) for sure instead of just in source code.

Comment: Is there casefolding in PHP? If not, am I okay with casefolding program identifiers to uppercase instead of lowe case? I've heard that lowercase fails in some languages.

Comment: There is `$str = mb_convert_case($str, MB_CASE_FOLD, "UTF-8");` to use instead of `strtoupper()`. But is it significantly slower?

Answer (score 1):

Specify a locale for toLowerCase() instead of using the system default. This protects against changes to the system locale.

As for possible unicode changes in future version of Java, I don't think it's worth writing code to handle this. Document that the product supports Java 6 and move on to a feature that your customers actually want.

Comment: Java6’s `toLowerCase()` is buggy.  You really need Java7.  Honest.

Comment: @Joachim: Personal experience, discovery, and bug reporting on the `i18n-dev@openjdk.java.net` mailing list. They were only changing letters; that’s not right, because if it *has* a lowercase mapping, you need to apply it no matter the general category. This shows up in things like Roman numerals. I could point you at the checkin for the fix if I have more time. This is connected with checks for lowercase, which forgot to use the Lowercase property instead of GC=Ll, which doesn’t work. It’s fixed now.

Comment: @Joachim Furthermore, you mustn’t try doing your own *casemapping* when what you need is *casefolding.*  There are 116 total code points whose casefolds cannot be derived from their lowercase (nor title‐ nor uppercase) mappings. Plus Java has a mismatch between how it does **full** casemapping (although not for titlecase, which it forgot!) but only **simple** casefolding. For example, Java’s uppercase of the 4-char string "ﬂour" is the 5-char "FLOWER", but Java’s incomplete casefolding won’t allow it to match that even under `UNICODE_CASE|CASE_INSENSITIVE`. You must compute the folds yourself

Comment: @tchrist: since you seem to be "in the known" for the topic, I'll take the chance to ask this: do you know if [ICU/ICU4J](http://userguide.icu-project.org/) handles this better (or even correctly)?

Comment: @Joachim Yes, ICU4J does everything better. Use [UCharacter](http://icu-project.org/apiref/icu4j/com/ibm/icu/lang/UCharacter.html) instead of Java’s `Character` for example. Alas, its excellent and standards-conforming regexes require JNIing into the C/C++ bindings, the way Android does it. Luckily that JNI/wrapper code is open source: look for `NativeRegEx.cpp` in the Android public source repository. NB: Instead of using casefolding in the regex engine, better sometimes to 1st generate the full casefold and then do a case SENSITIVE match against that, understanding what casefolds look like.

Answer (score 0):

I think the most long term solution is to

- record the current default locale and technology stack version (in my case Java version) into configuration
- if it's changed (since last start up, or running for locale - depending on how it's loaded by said technology stack), then lock the store and re-index all affected data sets.

Obviously, this needs to occur at the primary interface level; if I'm doing these changes in java, I better hope that it's my only data interface mechanism (e.g. that other techs are not querying the underlying table store)