# How do I case fold a string in Python 2?

Tags: python, unicode, python-2.x

Python 3.3 adds the `casefold` method to the str type, but in 2.x I don't have anything. What's the best way to work around this?

Comment: do you need to deal with non-English strings?

Comment: Yes. I want to run the unicode case folding algorithm.

Answer (score 4):

Check out [py2casefold](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/py2casefold).

```
>>> from py2casefold import casefold
>>> print casefold(u"tschüß")
tschüss
>>> casefold(u"ΣίσυφοςﬁÆ") == casefold(u"ΣΊΣΥΦΟσFIæ") == u"σίσυφοσfiæ"
True
```

Comment: [It doesn't seem to be very well tested](https://github.com/rwarren/py2casefold/blob/39a14b8971040b8f6015b7fa1a401c19c121175f/tests/test_casefold.py)

Comment: J.F. Sebastian -- what would you add?  For reference, [here](https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/d4669f43d05f/Lib/test/test_unicode.py#l568) is the extent of  python 3's `str.casefold` unit test.

Comment: see whether you'll manage to fish out a useful test from [`regex:test_case_folding()`](https://bitbucket.org/mrabarnett/mrab-regex/src/cbdb3caaee9ec68fdc2bff7e30902fb1dbdd3fd7/regex_3/Python/test_regex.py?at=default&fileviewer=file-view-default#test_regex.py-571)

Comment: J.F. Sebastian -- Thanks for the link, but there wasn't much useful I could see in that regex testing (a comment or two would be nice in there!).  Even still, I wasn't super pleased with the slim unit testing either, so I beefed it up a tad.  There really isn't much to the casefolding operation, though.  Not a heck of a lot that *can* be tested.

Comment: I can't believe that something is uncomplicated in Unicode e.g., are you sure no casefolding properties have been changed between different versions of the Unicode standard -- may I expect that casefold works the same between different Python 2 versions? Read [what @tchrist says on the related topic](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6996550/4279)

Comment: J.F. Sebastian -- I know what you mean, but case folding is actually fundamentally pretty simple.  @tchrist is 100% correct, but he is basically just saying to use the unicode casefold "algorithm" and *not* lowercase.  As far as functionality between python 2 versions, operation should be 100% identical.  The case folding operation is basically just a lookup table.  The key is to use the [master unicode table](http://www.unicode.org/Public/UNIDATA/CaseFolding.txt), which is currently at 8.0.0 (and included in the package).

Comment: Oh... and all the @tchrist tests will definitely pass (if he got them right :) ).  Several cases are already covered, and are pretty standard for case folding.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/90849/discussion-between-j-f-sebastian-and-russ).

Answer (score 2):

There is a thread [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1410308/how-to-implement-unicode-string-matching-by-folding-in-python) which covers some of the issues (but may not resolve all), you can judge whether it is suitable for what you need. If this is no good then there are some useful tips for implementing case folding on the W3C site [here](http://www.w3.org/International/wiki/Case_folding).

Answer (score 1):

If [PyICU](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/PyICU/) is already installed; you could use it to define `casefold()`. Using [the same example strings as in @Russ' answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32832057/4279):

```
>>> import icu
>>> casefold = lambda u: unicode(icu.UnicodeString(u).foldCase())
>>> print casefold(u"tschüß")
tschüss
>>> casefold(u"ΣίσυφοςﬁÆ") == casefold(u"ΣΊΣΥΦΟσFIæ") == u"σίσυφοσfiæ"
True
>>> icu.UNICODE_VERSION
'6.3'
>>> import unicodedata
>>> unicodedata.unidata_version
'5.2.0'
```

[The result may depend on the version of Unicode standard](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/25990557#25990557).