# While using casefold(), I am getting an error as " AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'casefold' "

Tags: python, python-2.6, case-folding

```
vowels = 'aeiou'

# take input from the user
ip_str = raw_input("Enter a string: ")

# make it suitable for caseless comparisions
ip_str = ip_str.casefold()

# make a dictionary with each vowel a key and value 0
count = {}.fromkeys(vowels,0)

# count the vowels
for char in ip_str:
    if char in count:
        count[char] += 1

print(count)
```

Error:

```
    Line - ip_str = ip_str.casefold()
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'casefold'
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Python 2.6 doesn't support the `str.casefold()` method.

From the [`str.casefold()` documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.casefold):

> New in version 3.3.

You'll need to switch to Python 3.3 or up to be able to use it.

There are no good alternatives, short of implementing the Unicode casefolding algorithm yourself. See [How do I case fold a string in Python 2?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18271077/how-do-i-case-fold-a-string-in-python-2)

However, since you are handling a *bytestring* here (and not Unicode), you could just use `str.lower()` and be done with it.

Comment: can you please explain me this statement


count = {}.fromkeys(vowels,0)

Comment: In the above comment what does { }.fromkeys() means

Comment: @NikhilKadam: it is a rather circumspect way of using the [`dict.fromkeys()` class method](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#dict.fromkeys), it creates a new dictionary with the elements from `vowels` as keys, each with a value set to `0`.

Answer (score 2):

In python 2.x you will get an error when you use `casefold()`.

You may just use `lower()`, these are not the same but comparable.

Read: [str.casefold()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.casefold)

> Casefolding is similar to lowercasing but more aggressive because it
>   is intended to remove all case distinctions in a string. For example,
>   the German lowercase letter 'ß' is equivalent to "ss". Since it is
>   already lowercase, lower() would do nothing to 'ß'; casefold()
>   converts it to "ss".