# How to check if File "mm" exists in uppercase like "mM" or "Mm" in linux

Tags: java, linux

so how may I check that? There are 36'000 files and on every event call I would need to check it, there could be plenty of these situations like: "nukasa" or "Nukasa" or "nUkasa", how may I detect all of these if I have one file name like: "NUKASA" or "nukasa" by event calling.

It's work with File not String. I just get String and then I need to work with File to check if in folder exists same file names just in Uppercase or Lowercase.

Comment: duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4446643/java-string-equalsignorecase-vs-switching-everything-to-upper-lower-case

Comment: what?? it's file not string in my situation..

Comment: Please clarify your question. In the title, you refer to a file, yet here, you refer to a string.

Comment: @user2638742 A file has a name, which is a String.

Comment: It's work with File not String. I just get String and then I need to work with File to check if in folder exists same file names just in Uppercase or Lowercase.

Comment: @user2638742 - read ZouZou's comment. If it's not enough, then show the code that you're using and some helpful person will explain.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Please refer below the snippet I want to show as an example:

```
File sampleFile = new File("Nukasa");
String valueToCheck = "NUKASA";
if(sampleFile.getName().equalsIgnoreCase(valueToCheck))
{
  //Logic you want to code goes here
}
```

Alternatively, you can use file.getName().toUpperCase().equals(valueToCheck) (if you assign upper case string to the variable valueToCheck). Same applies to toLowerCase() method also
CAUTION: This approach works fine as long as the Locale is of English language. For other languages, it won't work as expected. So, equalsIgnoreCase() is the best way. Credits to the person who suggested this

Comment: `file.getName().toUpperCase().equals(valueToCheck)` is _not_ the same as using equalsIgnoreCase, it depends on your locale. Take `"i".toUpperCase().equals("I");` for example, it will fail if you set the language to turkish... I would reccomand to remove that part of your anwser.

Comment: Hi mata, I've added some note. Many thanks for your suggestions!

Answer (score 0):

For case insensitive string comparison, use the [String](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html) method `str1.equalsIgnoreCase(str2)`.