# Make the string case insensitive in java

Tags: java, string, search, case-sensitive, case-insensitive

I have a question in my app I have a `String` which contain a word for search, then I use this word to search from a long Text, I want that all words that contain the searched word to return (e.g. WoRd = word = WORD). Thanks.

```
private static int countWords(String tstr1, String string)
    {   
        int i = 0;
        Scanner s = new Scanner(tstr1);

        while (s.hasNext()) 
        {
            if (s.next().equals(string)) 
                i++;

        }

        return i;
    }
}
```

`String tstr1` is the text and `String string` is the searched key, now I want to count how many times the searched key is in text (to be case insensitive). Thanks

Comment: Can you post the code that you have tried?

Comment: are you looking for equalsIgnoreCase() or toLower() / toUpper(). if non of this please illustrate your question further

Comment: Yes I'm for loking equalsIgnoreCase() or toLower() / toUpper() and for exemple if my word for search is `word` and in the text is `words` I want to find it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To count words in paragraph with case insensitive we also used `Pattern` class with `while` loop:

### For example:

```
public class CountWordsInParagraphCaseInsensitive {


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        StringBuilder paragraph = new StringBuilder();
        paragraph.append("I am at office right now.")
                .append("I love to work at oFFicE.")
                .append("My OFFICE located at center of kathmandu valley");
        String searchWord = "office";
        Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(searchWord, Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE);
        Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(paragraph);
        int count = 0;
        while (matcher.find())
            count++;
        System.out.println(count);

    }

}
```

Answer (score 3):

What you are looking for is `equalsIgnoreCase` of the `String`class

> public boolean equalsIgnoreCase(String anotherString)
>
> Compares this String to another String, ignoring case considerations. Two strings are considered equal ignoring case if they are of the same length and corresponding characters in the two strings are equal ignoring case.

You can also use `toLowerCase()` or `toUpperCase()` but I think using `equalsIgnoreCase()` is more readable.

This is also more efficient as was pointed by [Bathsheba](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2380830/bathsheba). This is because `equalsIgnoreCase()` will stop comparing the string as soon as a mismatch occurs.

More on this [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#equalsIgnoreCase%28java.lang.String%29). Read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4446643/java-string-equalsignorecase-vs-switching-everything-to-upper-lower-case) too.

Comment: ...and more efficient.

Comment: @Bathsheba That's true too. I'll add that to the answer. Thank you !

Answer (score 1):

`java.lang.String` has a method `boolean equalsIgnoreCase(String anotherString)` which is what you should be using here.

It's preferred to converting the strings to lower or upper case prior to calling `.equals()`. Do in that requires you to operate on both strings in their entirety whereas `equalsIgnoreCase` can exit on the first mismatch.

Answer (score 1):

In this scenario we used `Pattern` class to achieve case insensitive in all case.
For example:

```
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

/**
*
* @author developerbhuwan
*/
public class HowToUseCaseInsensitive {

   public static void main(String[] args) {
       String searchKey = "cAt";
       String searchOn = "Cat is an animal";

      // In searchOn String is present but when
      // we use contains method of string then not found
      // due to case sensitive comparision
      if (searchOn.contains(searchKey)) {
          System.out.println("Cat found in searchIn String");
      } else {
          System.out.println("Cat not found in searchIn String");
      }

     // Output => Cat not found in searchIn String
     // To achieve case insensitive comparison
     // perfect solution for all case is by using
     // Pattern class as below
     if (Pattern.compile(Pattern.quote(searchKey),
        Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE).matcher(searchOn).find()) {
          System.out.println("Cat found in searchIn String");
    } else {
          System.out.println("Cat not found in searchIn String");
    }
   // Now Output => Cat found in searchIn String
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I updated my question can you tell me please how to implement this. To count how many times  the `searchKey` are in `searchOn`. Thank you!!!

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
if (string1.equalsIgnoreCase(string2)){
    Do.somthing 
}else{etc.}
```

**Note:** The method `equals()` is inherited from `Object`, so its signature should not be changed.