# compare String without large and lower case

Tags: java, string

I want to know if a word is the same as a other, but large and lower case shouldn't matter. 
some how like this:

```
String a = new String "test";
String b = new String "Test";
a.equals(b); // should be true;
```

Comment: `equalsIgnoreCase()`

Answer (score 10):

You can use [`String::equalsIgnoreCase`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#equalsIgnoreCase(java.lang.String))

```
boolean check = a.equalsIgnoreCase(b);
```

---

**Note :** the declaration of your Strings is not correct it should be :

```
String a = "test";// or String a = new String("test");
String b = "Test";// or String b = new String("Test");
```

Answer (score 2):

An alternative is to change both to [lowerCase](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#toLowerCase()) or [upperCase](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#toUpperCase()) and then compare:

```
String a = "test";
String b = "Test";
System.out.println(a.toLowerCase().equals(b.toLowerCase())); // prints true
```

Comment: This solution seems to be worse. First, equalsIgnoreCase is likely more optimized. Second, using equalsIgnoreCase is much clearer.

Comment: @Amongalen It likely is worse; hence why I started the post with "*An alternative is...*".

Comment: It might be worth noting that these options are not equivalent, as the case-transformations in unicode are not bijective - there are several upper-case letters that map to the same lower-case letter, and also several lower-case letters that map to the same upper-case. Some lower-case letters even map to multiple upper case letters (like German `ß` => `SS`). In addition, `String.equalsIgnoreCase` does not use locale specific casing rules, while `String.toLowerCase` and `toUpperCase` do. Short version - it's more complicated that most people think, and each version can yield surprising results.

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4446643/java-string-equalsignorecase-vs-switching-everything-to-upper-lower-case and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15518731/understanding-logic-in-caseinsensitivecomparator