# Java Beginner:nextLine problems, while and if loop errors

Tags: if-statement, while-loop

Hi I started Java 3 days ago and I'm doing a small bank account project to ask user for their name and balance and print out some messages based on the input.
My problems start from trying to verify whether the user's name is correct. Anyway here's the code

//Code Starts
package com.chief;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    int minAmount = 500;

    Scanner userInput = new Scanner(System.in);
    /* String verifyName = "Yes";*/

    System.out.println("Please enter your Account Name and Balance");
    System.out.println("Account Name: ");


    //Username here
    String userName = userInput.nextLine();
    System.out.println("Balance: ");

    //Account balance here
    double balance = userInput.nextDouble();
    System.out.println("Account Name: " + userName);


    // Verification
    System.out.println("Please verify your username, enter Yes to accept or No to cancel");
    String verifyName = userInput.nextLine();

    while (verifyName.equals("Yes")) {
        if (balance < 500) {
            System.out.println("Your balance is below the minimum requirement of " + minAmount + " please top up");
            System.out.println("Thank you for banking with King Solomon Bank");
            }
        if (balance > 500){
            System.out.println("Good");
        }
    } 
}
```

}

The program terminates after asking the user to input Yes or No but I think it worked the first time I tried. So I'm unable to enter that string

Also I was having troubles using the input for verifyName to run the while and if loops.
Any help is greatly appreciated.
Thanks

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I make my string comparison case insensitive?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2220400/how-do-i-make-my-string-comparison-case-insensitive)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following fixes needed:

```
    String verifyName = userInput.next(); // not nextLine()!

    if (verifyName.equalsIgnoreCase("Yes")) {  // you get to endless loop here, use case-insensitive comparison
```