# Apply function to all elements of a WrappedArray elegantly

Tags: scala, apache-spark

This:

```
val checkValue = udf { (array: WrappedArray[String], value: String) => array.contains(value) }
```

works if you do not worry about case of words.

I can apply `.toLowerCase()` to value easily enough to get this `...(value.toLowerCase() )`

But how to apply to the incoming array being WrappedArray and not externally?

Comment: `array.iterator.map(_.toLowerCase).contains(value.toLowerCase)`?

Comment: @LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez  why not an answer?

Comment: @LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez    yep indeed, will remember that

Comment: Well, it was so obvious in my mind that I was sure it wouldn't work for some reason :p

Comment: @LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez  well so be it, but the point was "elegant"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
array.contains(value)
```

is the same as

```
array.exists(_ == value)
```

The `_ == value` can be replaced by an arbitrary predicate.

In your case, it would be something like

```
array.exists(value.equalsIgnoreCase)
```

Also, note that `"ß".toUpperCase == "SS"` is true, whereas `"ß" == "SS".toLowerCase` and `"ß".compareIgnoreCase("SS")` are both false, see for example [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34966206/2707792).